# external reference with lyx

Tags: cross-referencing, lyx, xr

I am attempting to reference labels in an external LyX document. I have found how to do this using the `xr` package in `.tex` files. However, I see no way of doing this in LyX without having to export to `.tex` first. Has anyone figured out how to refernece external documents in LyX without having to export to `.tex` first?

Comment: I know nothing about lyx but doesn't it generate .aux files when used? `xr` just needs the aux file of the document it is referencing.

Comment: It does not - things actually seem to work without the aux file.. not sure how that is possible but xr but somehow be reading the .lyx file

Comment: LyX generates a `.tex` file in a temporary directory and runs e.g. `pdflatex` on that file, so the `.aux` file and other temporary files are generated in that temporary directory.

Comment: Related questions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134896/586 http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70988/586 http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39772/586

Comment: yes but how doex `xr` know what that temporary directory is?

Comment: (that is, i'm astounded that simply putting the file name in the preamble worked since i specified no directory)

Comment: If I were to guess, I'd assume that LyX uses the same temporary directory within a single session. If that is the case, the two `.tex` files will be in the same folder, and then you don't have to specify the folder.

Comment: ahh good call. that makes sense.